# Cookie returns null in Jquery post to MVC Core2 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

my cookie code returns null, I am trying to anonymous users activities and log to a file

Here is my code
and cookie is set as

```
  public IActionResult Index(string key, string value, int? expireTime)
    {
        key = "localhost";
        value = "Upload_Page";
        expireTime = 10000;
        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();

        if (expireTime.HasValue)
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime.Value);
        else
            option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10);

        Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);

        return View();
    }

 string key; string value; int? expireTime;



            key = Request.Cookies["key"];
            value = Request.Cookies["value"];
            expireTime = Int32.Parse(Request.Cookies["expireTime"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide your get logic. Make sure you are sending cookies via the response and getting cookies via the request as shown below:

```
    public IActionResult CreateCookie()
    {

        const string key = "localhost";
        const string value = "Upload_Page";
        var option = new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10) 
    };

        Response.Cookies.Append(key,value,option);

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult LoadCookie()
    {
        var userCookie = Request.Cookies["localhost"];
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Apologies, my get logic was in the new controller, which used the key = Request.Cookies["key"];  I have updated that to reflect Request.Cookies["localhost"];   thank you